# Easiest programmatic way to ensure all Pandas Series data types are nullable

Tags: python, pandas, io, nullable

I am writing a program that uses Pandas DataFrames internally. It is important for the program to exclusively use nullable Pandas data types. I can read in data using Pandas and then convert "integer-ish" and "boolean-ish" columns into nullable types, but ideally there would be an option to read in data as nullable data types originally.

Is there some sort of flag that tells Pandas "Always use nullable int and bool data types, and do not infer columns as floats if they can be represented with those types"?

For example, the following would all use extension (nullable) dtypes:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
pd.Series([1,2,None])
pd.Series([True,False,None])
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("1,1,NA\n"),header=None)
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
`pd.Series([1,2,None], dtype="Int64")`

`pd.Series([True,False,None], dtype="boolean")`

Comment: With `pd.read_csv` you can specify the types of the columns like `df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype = {'colname': float})`. More detail at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dtype option in the read_csv or other data reading methods to explicitly define the data types if you want to require the use of nullable data types for any or all columns. Using Pandas' nullable extension data types, you can define the nullable integer and boolean data types.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

nullable_int = pd.Int64Dtype()
nullable_bool = pd.BooleanDtype()

data = io.StringIO("1,1,NA\n")
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, dtype={0: nullable_int, 1: nullable_int, 2: nullable_int})

s = pd.Series([1, 2, None], dtype=nullable_int)
print(s)

s = pd.Series([True, False, None], dtype=nullable_bool)
print(s)
```

Also You can define your custom data types using Pandas' nullable extension data types like pd.Int64Dtype() for nullable integers and pd.BooleanDtype() for nullable booleans.